# How to change fieldName value in identify popup panel

Tags: fields-attributes, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm newbie in this ArcGIS API for javascript.
The problem is I want to change the fieldName value . In SQL Query, it is like

```
Select ....,Length_m_,  CASE WHEN Length_m_ <= 0 OR
Length_m_ IS NULL THEN '-' ELSE CONVERT(nvarchar(50), CONVERT(decimal(10, 8), Length_m_)) END AS newLength.
```

The output is like this

[image]

Here is my code:

```
/// Bridge 5: {
title: 'Bridge',
description: [
'<table class="attrTable">',
'<tr><td rowspan="3" class="attrName">.........</td>',
'<td>',
'<table class="attrTable">',
..........
'<tr valign="top">',
'<td class="attrName">Length(km):</td>',
'<td class="attrValue">{Length_m_}</td>',
'</tr>',
'<tr valign="top">',
'<td class="attrName">Lane:</td>',
'<td class="attrValue">{Lane}</td>',
'</tr>',
'</table></td></tr></table>' 
].join(''),
}
```

So the output will be like;
[image]

How I can solve this porblem?

Comment: I tried to format the code to make it more readable - please edit my changes if necessary. Can you please also edit your code section to include more information? What are you calling in order to get this code fragment to run?

Answer (score 1):

Your sql query outputs the value you want to display in a new field `newLength`. So update your template to get data from that field instead of `Length_m_`, just replace `{Length_m_}` with `{newLength}`.
If that returns no data, you may have to republish your layer, making sure it contains that `newLength` field as an attribute.